# How to reset / clear IRQ requests in AX5043

Tags: rf, interrupts, transmitter

Has anyone gained experience with Onsemi's RF Transceiver AX5043?! I'm not able to clear the interrupt request Bits. For example my XTALREADY interrupt is fired immediately after reset and fired again and again when I activate the related interrupt mask. There are some interrupt inversion registers but they do not take effect.

http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9347-D.PDF

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is, to accept this bug! Onsemi answered my question and confirms that there is a bug without any workaround.